# How to use a cell containing HTML and variables for htmlBody in sendEmail

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a template for an automatic emailer spreadsheet and I'm trying to work out if it's possible to combine variables with text when it's drawn from a cell.  Which would allow a generic spreadsheet be used for multiple purposes with no code editing.

So in my settings sheet I have a email body cell B2.  It is possible to have html in the email as well as variable from an array e.g.

"Dear " + firstName +"."
+"thank you for your emails"

```
var firstName = row[0]
var message = settings.getRange("B2").getValue()
MailApp.sendEmail({
to: emailAddress,
cc: closedCopy,
subject: subjects,
htmlBody: message,
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Sending Email Based Upon Cell Values

### Using Timed Based Triggers

This function insures that all necessary data is properly entered prior to authorization sending each email.
In particular it also checks to see that DateSent is blank and that SendIfYes is 'Yes'.
Inaddition it is setup to provide log entries every ten minutes and to check for and set Emails that have the correct data and also have DateSent='' and SendIfYes='Yes'.

In order to get this to work for you, first you must create and timebased trigger for it.  I tested it with a 10 minute trigger and it worked fine.  You may setup these triggers
in your Script Editor Edit/Current Project Triggers menu or you may simply run the setupEmailTrigger from the provided 'My Tools' menu.  If you wish to terminate the timebased triggering
you may do so by utilizing the delEmailTrigger command in the 'My Tools' menu.  You may also run the script manually from the 'My Tools' menu.

You will have to fill in the DataFolderID and DefaultFileName in the saveFile function.

SendingEmail.gs:

```
function sendingMyEmails() 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sht=ss.getSheetByName('EmailSetup');
    var rng=sht.getDataRange();
    var rngA=rng.getValues();
    var s='\n' + 'Checking for Emails that need to be sent';
    for(var i=2;i<rngA.length;i++)
    {
      var dataA={};
      for(var j=0;j<rngA[1].length;j++)
      {
        dataA[rngA[1][j]]=rngA[i][j];
      }
      if(dataA.EntryDate && dataA.Name && dataA.Email && dataA.Subject && dataA.Body && dataA.SendIfYes=='Yes' && dataA.DateSent=='' && dataA.SendAs)
      {
        //MailApp.sendEmail(dataA.Email, dataA.Subject, dataA.Body, {replyTo:dataA.Sender});
        GmailApp.sendEmail(dataA.Email, dataA.Subject, dataA.Body, {replyTo: dataA.Sender,from: dataA.SendAs,htmlBody: dataA.Body});
        s+='\n' + 'Email Sent: Row: ' + Number(i+1) + ' Name: ' + dataA.Name + ' Email: ' + dataA.Email + ' Subject: ' + dataA.Subject + ' EntryDate: ' + dataA.EntryDate;
        sht.getRange(i+1,8).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-6', "M/dd/yyyy'\n'HH:mm:ss"));
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
      else
      {
        var row=Number(i+1);
        s+='\n' + 'Email Not Sent: Row: ' + Number(i+1) + ' Name: ' + dataA.Name + ' Email: ' + dataA.Email + ' Subject: ' + dataA.Subject + ' EntryDate: ' + dataA.EntryDate + ' SendIfYes: ' + dataA.SendIfYes + ' Date Sent: ' + dataA.DateSent;
      }
    }
    s+='\n';
    logEntry(s);
}

function setupEmailTrigger()
{
  nMinuteTrigger('sendingMyEmails');
  logEntry('\n10 Minute trigger setup for sendingMyEmails.');
}

function delEmailTrigger()
{
  delTriggers('sendingMyEmails');
  logEntry('\nDeleted All Project Triggers for sendingMyEmails.');
}
```

Code.gs:

```
function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
      .addItem('sendingMyEmails','sendingMyEmails')
      .addItem('setupEmailTrigger','setupEmailTrigger')
      .addItem('delEmailTrigger','delEmailTrigger')
      .addToUi();      
}

function nDayTrigger(funcName,n) 
{
  var n = (typeof(n) != 'undefined')?n:1;
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcName).timeBased().everyDays(n).create();
}

function nHourTrigger(funcName,n)
{  
  var n = (typeof(n) != 'undefined')?n:1;
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcName).timeBased().everyHours(n).create();
}

function nMinuteTrigger(funcName,n)
{
  var n = (typeof(n)!='undefined')?n:10;
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcName).timeBased().everyMinutes(n).create();
}

function delTriggers(funcName)
{
  if(funcName)
  {
    var triggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<triggers.length;i++)
    {
      if(triggers[i].getHandlerFunction()==funcName)
      {
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Invalid Parameter', 'funcName is undefined or invalid in function delTriggers in Code.gs', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}

function logEntry(entry,file)
{
  var file = (typeof(file) != 'undefined')?file:'eventlog.txt';
  var entry = (typeof(entry) != 'undefined')?entry:'No entry string provided.';
  if(entry)
  {
    var ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'hh:mm:ss a");
    var s = ts + ' - ' + entry + '\n';
    saveFile(s, file, true);
  }
}

function saveFile(datstr,filename,append)
{
  var append = (typeof(append) !== 'undefined')? append : false;
  var filename = (typeof(filename) !== 'undefined')? filename : DefaultFileName;
  var datstr = (typeof(datstr) !== 'undefined')? datstr : '';
  var folderID = (typeof(folderID) !== 'undefined')? folderID : DataFolderID;
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var file = fldr.getFilesByName(filename);
  var targetFound = false;
  while(file.hasNext())
  {
    var fi = file.next();
    var target = fi.getName();
    if(target == filename)
    {
      if(append)
      {
        datstr = fi.getBlob().getDataAsString() + datstr;
      }
      targetFound = true;
      fi.setContent(datstr);
    }
  }
  if(!targetFound)
  {
    var create = fldr.createFile(filename, datstr);
    if(create)
    {
      targetFound = true;
    }
  }
  return targetFound;
}
```

My Spreadsheet Header:

[image]

Comment: Hi Cooper,  Thanks for the response.  I was just looking through and it looks as though the code is a bit too complicated for what I'm aiming for.  I'm only using a single cell for all the emails which is "B2" which will contains the HTML and the variables.  When I used my code the HTML worked but the variables part didn't.  I.e. the <br> worked to create new lines but when I used + firstName to call the variable it put it in the email as a string (?) not as the variable.

Comment: I added the htmlBody in the options.

Comment: Hi, HTML is all working fine.  It's using the variables in the body. i.e.
In the script

    var firstName = row[0]
    var message = ss.getRange("B2")

In the sheet cell B2 will contain the message but I'd like the message to include the variables e.g.

Dear firstName

And it will pull the correct first name from the email sheet.  It might not be possible?

Comment: You just need to figure out how you wish to organize the columns of different variables.  If you want multiple choices you can use validation. Lets say you're going to have a Greeting , a FirstName and a Close then you could say that `if(dataA.Greeting && dataA.FirstName && dataA.Close){var message=dataA.Greeting + ' ' + dataA.FirstName + ',\n ' + dataA.Body + '\n\n' + dataA.Close;}` and we use message instead of body.  Personally, I don't write many emails so I don't see any value in such a thing but it's your code so your get to choose.

Comment: That makes so much sense.  I was over complicating it I think when all I needed to do was the same I've been doing in all the other auto email scripts I did!  Thanks!  I've marked as correct.